# Proper positioning of CSS elements

Tags: css-position

How has the medium-blog achieved the positioning of the metabar above the main tag without using position: absolute?

https://medium.com/personal-growth/building-a-life-on-the-foundation-of-faith-8dfeb0a27ee4

I think a brief explanation will suffice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[image: They used position fixed]

They used fixed positioning. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#Fixed_positioning).